# How to convert a doubly quoted symbol to a string

Tags: common-lisp

I know how to convert a symbol to a string: `(symbol-name 'hello)` or `(string 'hello)` returns `"Hello"`. What if the symbol is quoted twice? For example: `''hello`. `(string ''hello)` results in an error. In SBCL, the error message is: `'HELLO is not a string designator.`. How do I convert `''hello` to `"HELLO"`?

Comment: Despite this question already being answered, I think the biggest question here is: why do you have a quoted symbol? Should it really be there?

Comment: I agree with @LeonardoDagino: almost certainly if you are having to do this there is some confusion elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Just check in the REPL what the data looks like. `*` is a variable bound to the last evaluation result.

```
CL-USER 1 > 'hello
HELLO

CL-USER 2 > (string *)
"HELLO"

CL-USER 3 > ''hello
(QUOTE HELLO)

CL-USER 4 > (string (second *))
"HELLO"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `''hello` is equivalent to `(quote (quote hello))`, you can do:

```
CL-USER> (string (cadr ''hello))
"HELLO"
```

You could also use `eval` to evaluate the outer `quote`:

```
CL-USER> (string (eval ''hello))
"HELLO"
```

Comment: EVAL is not necessary, don't use it.